# EntityListBuilder only shows the last Entity that was added

Tags: 8, entities

I've build up an Entity for my module.
The problem is that the EntityListBuilder doesn't show all the entities that I've added. Only the last entity that I added shows up.

[Here is the drupal sandbox link](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-prateeksachan-2275583?h=8.x-1.x)

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityListBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
/**
 * Provides a listing of Example.
 */
class myentityListBuilder extends ConfigEntityListBuilder {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildHeader() {
    $header['name'] = t('myentity name');
    $header['status'] = array(
      'data' => t('Status'),
      'class' => array(RESPONSIVE_PRIORITY_MEDIUM),
    );

    $header['status'] = array(
      'data' => t('Status'),
      'class' => array(RESPONSIVE_PRIORITY_MEDIUM),
    );

    $header['myentity_status'] = array(
      'data' => t('myentity Status')
    );
    return $header;
  }
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildRow(EntityInterface $entity) {
    $row['title'] = array(
      'data' => $this->getLabel($entity),
      'class' => array('myentity-label'),
    );
    $row['status'] = $entity->status;
    $row['myentity_status'] = 'green';
    return $row + parent::buildRow($entity);
  }

  public function getDefaultOperations(EntityInterface $entity) {
    $operations = parent::getDefaultOperations($entity);
    return $operations;
  }

  public function load() {
    return parent::load();
  } 

  public function render() {
    $build = parent::render();
    $build['#empty'] = t('No myentitys available. <a href="@link">Add new myentity</a>.', array(
      '@link' => \Drupal::urlGenerator()->generateFromPath('admin/config/search/mymodule/myentitys/add'),
    ));
    return $build;
  }

}
?>
```

The entities are getting saved as I checked them from the config table in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that [the entity annotation](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-prateeksachan-2275583/tree/src/Entity/Cluster.php?h=8.x-1.x&id=f5f33fa7f1090ca2c3f75bfa69dec225d5cfcc82#n28) contains `"id" = "machine_name"` while [the configuration schema](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-prateeksachan-2275583/tree/config/schema/cluster.schema.yml?h=8.x-1.x&id=f5f33fa7f1090ca2c3f75bfa69dec225d5cfcc82)  does not contain `machine_name` and so the saved entities won't contain `machine_name` and they can't load. Make sure the id (which is often simply called `id` in this case it's called `cluster_id`) is in the schema and also in the entity class (in this case, it's `cluster_id` that is being manipulated, `machine_name` is the type of it in the form).